# How can i put number of line in Oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm a doubt.

I would like to know how can i put numbers of line in Oracle sql developer.
I think i need change something in tools > preferences, but i don't know how to do.

Thanks

[Oracle Sql Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXUeD.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click in the gutter.

[image]

It's also in the preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open Oracle SQL Developer and follow the below steps-

- List item
- Go to **Tools**-->**Preferences**
- Expand **Code Editor**
- Click on **Line Gutter**
- Enable **Show Line Numbers**

Done!